# How to add a session type button to lightdm-webkit-greeter theme?

Tags: unity, gnome, themes, lightdm, login-screen

I'm experimenting with the webkit greeter for lightdm. Ubuntu 13.10 64 bits. I want to learn to create my own themes. I noticed that the default theme does not show a language select button or a session type select button. With the unity-greeter I can choose to start Unity or Gnome 3. Recently I started to prefer Gnome 3, that means that the webkit greeter is unusable to me right now as I'm forced to start with Unity when I want Gnome 3.

Is It possible to add a session type button to a webkit-greeter theme? How? Must I edit the default theme files to show the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `lightdm-webkit-greeter.c` in the source code, there are all sorts of interesting values we can get at from webkit. For a quick and dirty method to add a session selection dropdown to the default theme I did the following (this could definitely be expanded and improved upon):

In the default `index.html`, right above the line that writes the user list to the greeter:

```
document.write('<table id="user_table" style="margin: auto;">');
```

I added some code to write out the session selector:

```
document.write('<select id="session_list">');
for (i in lightdm.sessions)
{
  session = lightdm.sessions[i];
  if (session.key == lightdm.default_session)
    document.write('<option selected="selected" value="' + session.key + '">' + session.name + '</option>');
  else
    document.write('<option value="' + session.key + '">' + session.name + '</option>');
}
document.write('</select>');
```

The `value` attributes aren't really necessary in this code, I was going to use them to select the session, but decided to use the index instead. The other change is to the `authentication_complete()` function. In the default code we have:

```
if (lightdm.is_authenticated)
  lightdm.login (lightdm.authentication_user, lightdm.default_session);
```

So it always uses the `default_session` key. We want to instead use the selected session, so we can do something like:

```
if (lightdm.is_authenticated)
{
  session_list = document.getElementById('session_list');
  session = lightdm.sessions[session_list.selectedIndex];
  lightdm.login (lightdm.authentication_user, session.key);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that code. I learned a lot about how the greeter works. If I understand correctly that code, the session list will be placed right above the user list, and its starting value will be always the default_session at each system boot, and its last selected value will be maintained for the next user except when explicitly changed. Depending of what I can get from the lightdm namespace/object I will try to get a behavior similar to the unity-greeter that remembers the last session chosen by each user.

Comment: @HatoruHansou That is partially correct. The default value will actually always be the `default-session` key in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, however the user's session choice is updated correctly. I thought I'd start with something simple, but it shouldn't be too hard to extend it to have per-user sessions. You should be able to get the session key from the user object as `user.session`, and use that to compare instead of `lightdm.default_session`.

Comment: Thank you for clarify. And user.session is definitely what I'm after.